# Use grep with python subproccess.check_output and adb logcat

Tags: android, python, bash, testing, grep

I am trying to write a python function that captures the time it takes for an android device to get gps fix. I want to do this by capturing the timestamp of the logcat record which mentions that system time is syncronised with GPS. So I submit an adb logcat with timestamp and grep for "Setting system time at". The I want to give the timestamp value of this line to a varialble. Specifically I want to capture the characters 10-18 of this line as this reflects the exact time from device boot. Once the string has been detected once I want the function to exit and my program to continue.

I try in the following:

```
cmdtimegps='adb logcat -v time| grep "Setting system time at"'
w=subprocess.check_output(cmdtimegps.split())
print w
```

My main problem is making the command (adb logcat -v time| grep SetTimeFromGPSService) work. I get a "/system/bin/sh: grep: not found" error. Any help with this or advice on the following steps would be very welcome. Many thanks in advance,

Comment: have you tried `check_output(..., shell=True)`?

Comment: yes, `shell=True` and without the `.split()` then.

Comment: originally I got a "/system/bin/sh: grep: not found" and "broken pipe" error. If I change my statement as:"w=subprocess.check_output(cmdtimegps.split(), shell=True)" then I get a: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "JUNK.py", line 81, in test2
    w=subprocess.check_output(cmdtimegps.split(), shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 544, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
CalledProcessError: Command '['adb', 'logcat', '-v', 'time|', 'grep', '"Setting', 'system', 'time', 'at"']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Comment: Did you try without the split, as @Alfe suggested?

Comment: without the .split() part and with shell=True the script stalls. Nothing happens until I  ctl+c

Comment: the exact error now is: File "JUNK.py", line 81, in test2
    w=subprocess.check_output(cmdtimegps, shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 538, in check_output
    output, unused_err = process.communicate()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 746, in communicate
    stdout = _eintr_retry_call(self.stdout.read)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 478, in _eintr_retry_call
    return func(*args)

Comment: So, what happens if you run `adb logcat -v time| grep "Setting system time at"` in a system shell?

Comment: Then it works just fine and returns what I expect

Comment: which is: 01-01 01:00:44.670 I/SetTimeFromGPSService(  262): Setting system time at 946684844675 to 1382431181800 (delta 435746337125ms) from Location[mProvider=gps,mTime=1382431181800,mLatitude=50.37657494,mLongitude=4.50853686,mHasAltitude=true,mAltitude=136.0,mHasSpeed=true,mSpeed=0.0,mHasBearing=false,mBearing=0.0,mHasAccuracy=true,mAccuracy=20.52,mExtras=Bundle[{}]]

Comment: no it does not terminate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of problems. First, this is a piped shell command so you need to pass the string without splitting it into a list and set shell=True. Second, check_output is a bad choice here because it only returns after the program terminates but your particular command runs forever.

A better solution is to stop grepping and have python process the command. Then you can kill it when you see the data you want.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['adb', 'logcat', '-v', 'time'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in proc.stdout:
    if "Setting system time at" in line:
        proc.kill()
        break
proc.wait()
```

Comment: This quickly solves the problem, thank you very much for your help!